# How to close a PDA account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, account

```
 #[account(
        init,
        seeds = 
        [   
            b"config".as_ref(),
            mint.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        payer = sender,
        space = 90
    )]
    pub freezing_config : Account<'info,FreezingConfig>,
```

What seeds should i add to make the account unique everty time for the same mint address?

can anyone share how can i close this account with a small snippet?

Comment: These are two separate questions. If you link me another question that you post I'll be happy to answer each question individually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the "recommended" example to close an account from common `sealevel-attacks`, there are also examples of "insecure" and "secure" ways to close an account to review if you are interested:

https://github.com/coral-xyz/sealevel-attacks/tree/master/programs/9-closing-accounts

```
#[program]
pub mod closing_accounts_recommended {
    use super::*;

    pub fn close(ctx: Context<Close>) -> ProgramResult {
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Close<'info> {
    #[account(mut, close = destination)]
    account: Account<'info, Data>,
    #[account(mut)]
    destination: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Data {
    data: u64,
}
```

Comment: is there a generic way to close an account without having to define his corresponding `struct Data`? It would be really handy for situations where the struct of an account has changed and you want to get rid of old accounts with the "wrong" data structure.

Comment: How comes this approach doesn't need seeds or bump? I thought it was required when using PDA accounts.