# Gasless Transactions for Solana

Tags: transactions, account, transfer, fees, economics

Has there been any research or development done around gasless txns? I'm looking to record particular txns for user provenance that have little intrinsic value now, but likely will in the future.

I'm trying to avoid forcing a user to spend gas on a tx that does not immediately help their experience or provide value.

Thanks.

-K

Answer (score 1):

No, every transaction in Solana has to pay a certain transaction fee.

[Calculating Solana Fees](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/calculating-solana-fees)

But you can close accounts to retrieve your Sol back. So you might add an instruction that closes the user's PDA in case he doesn't want to interact with the program anymore. In that case, he will get the Sol back.

[Close smart contract to get deployment funds back?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/close-smart-contract-to-get-deployment-funds-back)

[How to close a PDA account?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/how-to-close-a-pda-account)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good summary on the behavior - thank you.  I see things like https://github.com/solana-labs/octane trying to get creative with the tx processing and how fees are proxied into sol.  Please all keep the thoughts and comments coming - the feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I was going to post about Octane, that's your best bet at the moment.